# Set field to readonly if currently edited user has higher privelage

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

So my goal is to have group of users that are able to add new users but they should not have other admin privelages.

The way I want to solve it is by having group with permissions to only add users and another group with all the admin right. For this to be scure I need to prevent users in the first group from editing users in the second group.

I have module with this code:

```xml
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_user_readonly" >
    <field name="name">res.users.form.readonly</field>
    <field name="model">res.users</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_users_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='login']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="readonly">True</attribute>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

And it sets field to readonly for all the users. Now I would like to change is so that it is readonly when user we are trying to edit has the group `base.group_system` and we don't.

I tried adding code based on anwsers from the internet like this:

```xml
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_user_readonly" >
    <field name="name">res.users.form.readonly</field>
    <field name="model">res.users</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_users_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='login']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="readonly">True</attribute>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>

<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_user_readonly_settings">
    <field name="name">res.users.form.readonly.settings</field>
    <field name="model">res.users</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="custom_user_fields.view_user_readonly" />
    <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('base.group_system')])]"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='login']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="readonly">False</attribute>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

But it does not work as intended. It restrict everyone without `base.group_system` from editing and I need to allow other users to edit this field in some cases (for example while creating new users). Or if it is possible - set this field to readonly only when user we are editing have "base.group_system" and we don't.

**#EDIT**
Internal users should not be able to edit other users. Manager (user with group Access Rights - `group_erp_manager`) should be able to edit Internal users and other managers but not admins. Admin (user with group Settings - `group_system`) should have access to edit everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by editing you mean stop the user from editing any field
you really have a lot of cases, because you need to check 
for example:

```
1. manager cannot create an admin user
2. manger cannot make him self admin but can create other manager or normal users
```

I created a application for this but really it's not with now 
it's in work.

Okay i'm going to try a simple solution that allow a manager
to edit any user but stop him with error message if he is trying  to edit a admin.

```py
@api.multi
def check_editing_previlage(self):
    """ check if users is allowed to edit this record."""
    # admin can do what ever he wants
    if self.env.user.has_group('base.group_system'):
        return True
    if self.env.user.has_group('base.group_erp_manager'):
        # 1. admin can create a user
        if isinstance(self.id, models.NewId):
            return True
        # 2. he is not allowed to edit and admin
        if self.has_group('base.group_system'):
            return False
        # 3. he is allowed to edit this users
        return True

    # other user are not allowed to edit any user
    return False



@api.mutli
def write(self, vals):
    for rec in self:
        if not rec.check_editing_previlage():
            # show a nice error that tells the user that he is not allowed to edit 
            # this user
            raise exceptions.ValidationError(_('''You are not allowed to edit user %s contact your manager
                                               if you think that is an error.
                                               ''') % rec.name)
    # continute the editing otherwise 
    return super(ClassName, self).write(vals)
```

The problem with this solution is that a manager can make him self or another use an admin .
In order for you to stop this you need to check what are the groups that are added
and removed and raise an exception if a non admin user is trying
to add or remove an admin previlage. you can post another question and specify the what 
Odoo version you are using.

Comment: Thanks! I had small trouble with invisibility attribute of field `id`. I think there is a typo in "invisbile" but at last I got it working with `attrs="{'invisible': 1}"`. And I have a couple questions. First is why do you clear all attributes of `login` field? Shoudn't we clear only `readonly` attribute? And what exactly do you mean with adding priority? How do I do this?

Comment: And also is there a way to check if user we are currently editing have particular group? I would like to turn readonly off if edited user does not have `base.group_system`.

Comment: no I didn't mean to clear all attribute i'm just giving you the Idea, and sorry for my syntax error in `invisible="1"`. I think using compute field is more safe and easy. don't clear all attribute if there is i'm just giving the idea, did it work the second solution, I know the first one work perfectly

Comment: after reading your second comment go with the first solution you requirement is to complicated to do it with XML only

Comment: Sadly at the moment it isn't easier for me and I don't know how to do this exactly.

Comment: okay just edit your question and tell me when a normal user is allowed to edit the login field and I will show you how to do it

Comment: it's not that hard, just create a compute field and use it in attrs to make the login field readonly dynamically.

Comment: removing the edit button for this situations is impossible without having to deal with `Javascript`, making fields readonly how many field you need to make it readonly when a manager is trying to edit an admin, I had a requirement like this an even more complected I needed to check the company too. best way is to do a verification in `create` and `write` method to see what groups are added and removed. just ask another question you will get help. if not I may have time to help you later. and remember to specify what version you are using

Comment: just try my solution to have an idea if you like it, Just ask how to check if a manger is trying to create or edit an admin ^^

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try implementing it ^^ A while back I solved the problem with manager giving himself admin rights by moving the `Settings` group from `Administration` to `Extra Rights` - and this extra rights section is only visible to people with `Settings` group.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need admin permissions for some users as we have already and for some users only create permission not edit. If you need users with the group 'group_system' only create permission not edit , then please follow the below code:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_user_readonly_settings">
<field name="name">res.users.form.readonly.settings</field>
<field name="model">res.users</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="custom_user_fields.view_user_readonly" />
<field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('base.group_system')])]"/>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//form" position="attributes">
        <attribute name="create">1</attribute>
        <attribute name="edit">0</attribute>
    </xpath>
</field>
```

users with the group 'group_system' will only have create permission with Some login (editable). They cannot edit old records.

Comment: First of all - I tried this solution and it does not work (although not with a custom module but with odoo developer UI). I even posted an issue on odoo github but sadly they don't consider it a bug:
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/35480

And there is a small misunderstanding. Because I want the group `group_system` to be a superuser. I have other group that should have restricted access.

Comment: Instead of the super user permission you have created one new group for some users. Could you please let us know the access given for new group for the model res_users like                                                                                                                                           access_res_users_new_group,access_res_users_new_group,,model_res_users,group,1,1,0,0

Comment: I have group Access Rights (group_erp_manager) that should be able to add new users and I have group Settings (group_system) that should have other admin permissions.
My access rights for `res.users`: https://i.imgur.com/fMuzAvF.png
And record rules: https://i.imgur.com/ovMJNIF.png
I don't really understand the line with `field name="groups_id"` inside my code.